# What is *fill* section shows in the link map file?

Tags: gcc, arm, ld, u-boot, cortex-a8

Yesterday i created my own u-boot module and want to set text base address at 0xd0020010.
But after compiling, in the .map file generated by linker shows like this

```
inker script and memory map

                0x00000000                . = 0x0
                0x00000000                . = ALIGN (0x4)

.text           0xd0020010      0x1f0
                0xd0020010                __image_copy_start = .
 *(.vectors)
 *fill*         0xd0020010       0x10 00
 .vectors       0xd0020020       0x60 arch/arm/lib/built-in.o
                0xd0020020                _start
                0xd0020044                _undefined_instruction
                0xd0020048                _software_interrupt
                0xd002004c                _prefetch_abort
                0xd0020050                _data_abort
                0xd0020054                _not_used
                0xd0020058                _irq
                0xd002005c                _fiq
```

You can see above the .vectors section, there are 16 bytes of 0x00 which name is "*fill*".

And my link script is like this

```
    SECTIONS
    {
        . = 0x00000000;

        . = ALIGN(4);
        .text :
        {
            __image_copy_start = .;
            *(.vectors)
            CPUDIR/start.o (.text*)
            *(.text*)
        }
      .........
```

I tried to remove ALIGH(4), but it stand still. And 0xd0020010 is a aligned address right? So it should have no matter to do with "ALIGH"

Although the 16 bytes of memory are filled by 0x00, which are *nop* instructions, but i still wonder why there is a "*fill*" section.

Comment: Each *input section* may have an alignment.  32bytes is a common cache size, so it is quite possible that *arch/arm/lib/built-in.o* has an alignment of 0x20.  As your initial counter is not aligned to this, the linker use `*fill*` to pad the binary.  Run `objdump -h arch/arm/lib/built-in.o` and see what the **Algn** column says.

Comment: My u-boot has `objdump -h built-in.o | grep \.vector` giving *72 .vectors      00000300  00000000  00000000  000011e0  2\*\*5*, where the last `2**5` is why you have the alignment.  See: [vectors.S](http://git.denx.de/?p=u-boot.git;a=blob;f=arch/arm/lib/vectors.S;h=0cb87cee7f611ddb250b0ced65c5c816db0cc930;hb=HEAD#l228), where there is an `.align 5` directive.

Comment: What does 2**5 mean in the objdump ? And why does it use an align(5)? Typically it should be aligh(4) right?

Comment: The linker script you are editing is the linker script attached, correct? Are you definitely sure the linker script you attached (and editing) above is correct? There is discrepancy in the linker script and disassembly. The start of the script is 0x00000000 (denoted by ". = 0x00000000") but then the text section jumps to 0xdxxxxxxx in the disassembly.

Comment: Depending on platform ".align param" behaves direfferently. param can be bytes or number of low-order zero bits. From http://masahir0y.blogspot.jp/2012/06/gas-align.html (Yamada-san is a u-boot developer)

Comment: Sessyargc.jp thanks. i now understand what it means. aligned to 5 low-order zero bits mean the 5 low-oder bits of adress are zero , which means the address is multiple times of 32 bytes.